# How to refresh a token for a Twilio Conversation in the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-conversations

I'm using the `TwilioConversationsClient` on iOS. How do I generate a new token once my existing token has expired?

These delegate methods get called after the token expires.

```
- (void)conversationsClientTokenWillExpire:(TwilioConversationsClient *)client
{
    
}

- (void)conversationsClientTokenExpired:(TwilioConversationsClient *)client
{

}
```

I know I'm supposed to call this method to update the token for the client, but I don't understand how to generate a new token for an existing conversation using the iOS SDK.

```
[client updateToken:@"TOKEN" completion:^(TCHResult * _Nonnull result) {
    
}];
```

Comment: How did you generate the token in the first place?

Comment: From node.js, but I'm not able to find any example code for the client iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to generate a token from within the iOS SDK. Generating tokens requires your API secret and that should never be a part of the client-side code.

Instead, when the `conversationsClientTokenWillExpire` delegate method is called, you should make another request to your Node.js server to generate a new token. Once you have the new token, call `updateToken` on your Conversations Client and it will continue to work.